# Default yes to apt-get/aptitude install unless uninstall

Tags: apt-get, aptitude, apt

There's a lot of answers how to remove the need to type `Y` when using apt-get install (hint: use `-y` or `--yes`) and this works great until you run into dependency issues and the suggested action is to uninstall the package. At least aptitude does this sometimes.

I'm mainly using fabric and don't want to be prompted to accept if the package will be upgraded but without risking that the package ends up being uninstalled. Is there a good way to do this?